# Yargs .check() for specific conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, yargs

I currently have yargs working in an app that can run with no arguments, or EITHER or BOTH of the following:

> - a '-o' option with exactly one argument
> - a '-f' option with no arguments

These work, but nothing stops the user entering extra options or arguments which get ignored, e.g.:

> - app hello
> - app -f hello
> - app -o hello hello

I would rather fail and remind them of the usage. I think a .check() function is the right way, but I can not find many examples online. Could anyone suggest a check() function, if this is the right way forward?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, after some experimenting, it seems the following works:

```
.check(function (argv) {
        if (argv.f && argv.f !== true) {
            return false;
        }
        if (argv._.length) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    })
```

Hope that's helpful to someone in the future